# Call JSP with Apache HTTPClient and pass context and request

Tags: jsp, apache-httpclient-4.x

First of all: The code architecture behind my problem isn´t my fault :) I will explain it later...

The **BAD** situation:

- A JSP includes several JSP. One after each other with

`<jsp: include>`

- These several JSP are "userscripts". Our Consultants have to do custom programmings and don´t want to compile servlets ...
- The request may take too long...

My **IDEA**:

- Let the first JSP start a Thread
- The Thread calls all of those customer JSPs
- Call the JSP with [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/index.html)

My **Problem**:

- In the customer JSPs I can´t get access to the attributes I set in the first JSP.

My **Question**:

- How do I have to set the Parameters and pass it to the Customer JSPs?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the issue is the jsps are long running.  So why do HttpClient calls from the server back to the server as opposed to Ajax (Asynchronous....) calls from the client to the different pages on the server?

Comment: Thank for your idea. But that might not solve my problem because even one jsp request could take a looong time. And the client shouldn´t know about all those request. I think I will refactor a lot and will do it with a threaded servlet....